# Windows service not working

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wcf, service

I have prepared an application with WCF service library and Windows service. I have done the whole process with the help of the [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38160/WCF-Service-Library-with-Windows-Service-Hosting) from the Code Project.

After creating all the functionality of WCF, it built successfully and also created WCF DLL file. Now, I have created Windows Service project inside the same solution Explorer for hosting the service DLL. Inside the `OnStart` method I have written the below code:

```
namespace WindowsService1
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        ServiceHost sHost;
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            sHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1));
            sHost.Open();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            sHost.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

For adding the `WcfServiceLibrary1`, I have added the reference of the WCF DLL in this service. To do this, right click on the project in *Solution Explorer* and select *Add Reference*. For adding the DLL in reference, select browse tab in the window that appears, and navigate to the folder where our WCF service library is located. In that location, the DLL can be found inside the "bin\Release" folder.

After adding the reference it gives no error, but when I am going to the build the solution it gives the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'WcfServiceLibrary1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have added the reference once again, the error disappeared and then I have built the solution again. The same error message appeared.

I could not understand why is this happening. Even I have followed the link thoroughly and prepared the solutions once again from the beginning, but the same error message is coming each and every time.

**The above issue is resolved now by following toadflakz's answer.** Now, my service is installed correctly but getting the below exception at **OnStart.**

```
Service cannot be started. System.InvalidOperationException: Service 'WcfServiceLibrary1.WCFService' has zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no service element matching the service name could be found in the configuration file, or because no endpoints were defined in the service element.
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.EnsureThereAreApplicationEndpoints(ServiceDescription description)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object state)
```

I have tried many options and I am really struggling on this. Please help me get rid of this so that I can just start my service successfully.

Comment: After you build is that wcf dll in your executable's bin directory?

Comment: Try to add reference to your library project.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio is not picking up the dependency between your `WcfServiceLibrary1` project and your Windows Service project. You've linked to the DLL instead of the project, so VS doesn't know that it needs to build `WcfServiceLibrary1` output before your Windows Service project needs to reference it for compilation.

When you build a solution, all previous outputs (including DLLs) are deleted as part of the Clean stage of a build. This is why the `WcfServiceLibrary1.dll` cannot be found when building the Windows Service project.

The way to rectify this is to build against the project, not the DLL.

In Visual Studio: Right-click and select Add Reference -> Select the Projects tab -> Select "WcfServiceLibrary1" project -> Click Add Reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it has worked but facing another problem now. I am editing my question for that. Please see if you can help.

Comment: You need to add an `application.config` file to your service executable project and add the configuration which will have been generated in your service `assembly.config` file to it - assembly level config is not loaded by `ConfigurationManager` at runtime - only executable config is.